# Why is Bragg's Law always presented as $n\lambda=2d\sin \theta$?

Tags: diffraction, braggs-law

In the vast majority of texts and handbooks on Bragg diffraction, Bragg's formula is presented as:

$$n\lambda=2d\sin \theta\tag{1}$$

where $\theta$ is the incident angle.

But constructive interference occurs when:

$$n\lambda=\text{path difference between incident and reflected ray}$$

So, for example:

[image: Bragg diffraction]

then:

$$n\lambda=d\left(\sin\alpha + \sin\beta\right)\tag{2}$$

A long time ago I used that formula to determine the $d$-value of an R-DVD using a pen-type known wavelength red laser. Using $(1)$ I would only have 'seen' part of the constructive interferences (for $\alpha = \beta$).

**So why is only $(1)$ taught?**

Comment: The standard expression (1) seems to consider only reflection, where $\alpha = \beta = \theta$. My guess is the reflection direction has the strongest contribution to the interference pattern.

Comment: @EdV Nice photos! One publication I read that used $(1)$, called these diffractions 'specular' ('mirror like'). But it didn't explain why $(2)$ shouldn't be used or why $(1)$ is to be preferred. Of course when you look at a typical X-ray chrystallography set up, the angle of the detector is automatically adjusted to be equal to the angle of (specular) reflection, so that $(1)$ applies. That may well be the only reason: *convenience*. But the handbooks, papers and other texts that don't start from $(2)$ are *dishonest by omission*, IMO...

Comment: I'm planning another diffraction experiment, this one using $\alpha=\beta=\theta$, just to see...

Comment: @EdV I don't know about resolution. I use simple trigonom. to measure the $\beta$. The larger the triangles, the better the resolution. Re. $n\lambda=2d\sin\theta$ the more I think about it the more I'm convinced this comes from practical X-ray chryst. There for $\theta=\alpha =\beta$ the value of $\theta$ is varied slowly and a spectrum is recorded. The peaks and some nifty math then allows to compute the chrystal structure ($d_{klm}$ values).

Comment: Well, HR mirrors are basically special Bragg structures and they display only a specular characteristic. I do not know why there would be diffraction for the normal Fresnel type of case. I think the problem here is that you are considering also diffraction effects and not only refraction as is the case in dielectric mirror coatings.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your DVD experiment? Because in a DVD you are looking at diffraction typically, not the typical scenario where Bragg conditions are considered. Or, its a bit complicated. In x-ray crystallography you have to consider both diffractive and refractive effects and the concept of Bragg actually is already a mix of both. But for example in VIS and IR optics, the Bragg concept is also applied, but here it's always specular because there are no possibilities for diffraction.

Comment: (was reading a bit about this, I think the problem is that the definition of Bragg scattering is only for the specular diffraction, ie when $\alpha=\beta=\theta$. Other geometries just fall under diffraction. At least that is my interpretation.)

Comment: @JoséAndrade Sorry, yes the R-DVD experiment was just diffraction. I used $(2)$ to get multiple readings of $d$, then averaged. As coincidence would have it, my daughter carried out a near identical experiment at Uni around the same time.

Comment: Also, I misinterpreted your question. When I saw $n\lambda$ my brain locked into the concept of refractive index and I immediately thought of typical VIS and IR optics, also your DVD mention did not help. Either way, my interpretation of this whole thing is that the Bragg condition is just a fancy name for the specular case. Its useful because it allows for a very well determined angle experimentally, and hence allows for high-precision in measuring things.

Comment: My main immediate purpose is Bragg diffraction of VIS laser on a synthetic Opal. Interesting and a bit tricky too...